# Tkinter tags on Labels

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Using tkinter with Python 3

I have a frame which I bound a callback function to when I click the frame, but when I place widgets in the frame they don't respond to the click. So I want to bind them to the same callback function as the parent frame so that clicking anywhere in the frame works. Is there a way to assign a tag to a label widget so I can do a frame.tag_bind() and bind all the child widgets at once? Do frames even have a .tag_bind() method? Or do I have to bind all the widgets individually?

Here's some simplified code for the current situation.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Window():
    def __init__(self, master):
        master.geometry('100x100')
        frame = tk.Frame(master)
        frame.pack(fill='both', expand=1)
        frame.bind('<Button-1>', self.callback)
        label = tk.Label(frame, text='Label')
        label.pack()

    def callback(self, event):
        print(event.x)

root = tk.Tk()
Window(root)
root.mainloop()
```

---EDIT---
My actual code has more than one frame, so bind_all won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned you have more than one `frame` widget in you GUI, you can use the following method.

Use `frame_widget.winfo_children()` to get the `child widget(s)` inside of the `frame_widget`, then give the `callback` to each of the child widgets.

I have added another frame widget to the code you posted for the sake of visually understanding the method I used.

**Here is the code:**

```py
import tkinter as tk

class Window():
    def __init__(self, master):
        master.geometry('100x100')

        # --- frame 1 --- #
        frame1 = tk.Frame(master, bg='blue')
        frame1.pack(fill='both', expand=1)
        frame1.bind('<Button-1>', self.callback)

        label1 = tk.Label(frame1, text='Label 1 in frame 1')
        label1.pack()

        label2 = tk.Label(frame1, text='Label 2 in frame 1')
        label2.pack()

        # you can get the child widgets inside the frame and set callback
        for child_widget in frame1.winfo_children():
            child_widget.bind('<Button-1>', self.callback)
            
        # --- frame 1 --- #

        # --- frame 2 --- #
        frame2 = tk.Frame(master, bg='white')
        frame2.pack(fill='both', expand=1)
        #frame2.bind('<Button-1>', self.callback)

        label1 = tk.Label(frame2, text='Label 1 in frame 2')
        label1.pack()

        label2 = tk.Label(frame2, text='Label 2 in frame 2')
        label2.pack()
        # --- frame 2 --- #

    def callback(self, event):
            print(event.x)

root = tk.Tk()
Window(root)
root.mainloop()
```

[image: gui]

So `frame 1` is `blue` in color and `frame 2` is `white` in color.

Now you can click anywhere inside and on the `frame 1` including the `child widgets` and the assigned `callback` is triggered. On the other hand, the `frame 2` is not assigned any callback at all.

I have tried explaining with some theory. I hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can simulate the `tag_bind(...)` effect by adding a `tag_bind()` function to your `Window` class and assign an attribute `tag` to child widget of `Window` instance:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Window(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, *args, **kwargs)
        self.bind('<Button-1>', self.callback)

    def callback(self, event):
        print(event.x)

    def tag_bind(self, tag, callback=None):
        for child in self.winfo_children():
            if hasattr(child, 'tag') and child.tag == tag:
                child.bind('<Button-1>', callback if callback else self.callback)

root = tk.Tk()

win = Window(root, bg='yellow')
win.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

lbl1 = tk.Label(win, text='Label')
lbl1.tag = 'label'  # assign a tag to this label
lbl1.pack()

lbl2 = tk.Label(win, text='Blocked')
lbl2.pack()

lbl3 = tk.Label(win, text='Passed')
lbl3.tag = 'passed'  # assign another tag to this label
lbl3.pack()

win.tag_bind('label') # bind to default internal callback
win.tag_bind('passed', lambda e: print('passed')) # bind to external callback

tk.Frame(root, width=100, height=100, bg='blue').pack()

root.mainloop()
```

You can modify the `tag_bind()` function to suit your requirement.